# eslint wants me to add a dependency to useEffect but doing so causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I appreciate this is a common issue on here but I'm struggling to think of a workaround for my particular situation. My code works as intended but I'm getting an eslint warning about the missing dependency in `useEffect`. The missing dependency is a function which sends the state to the parent, but if I add it as a dependency it causes an infinite loop.

Here's my child component **CheckboxGroup.js**:

The `itemId` and `checkedState` get lifted from its child (CheckboxItem.js) and the `selectedItemIds` state gets updated. I've then used useEffect because `selectedItemIds` needs to get lifted to its parent (App.js) immediately. As you can see, it's missing `onSelectHandler` in its list of dependencies.

```
const CheckboxGroup = (props) => {
  const categoryName = props.items[0].category;

  const [selectedItemIds, setSelectedItemIds] = useState([
    ...props.defaultCheckboxIds,
  ]);

  const clickHandler = (itemId, checkedState) => {
    checkedState
      ? setSelectedItemIds((prev) => [...prev, itemId])
      : setSelectedItemIds((prev) => prev.filter((c) => c !== itemId));
  };

  //destructure prop
  const onSelectHandler = props.onSelectHandler;

  useEffect(() => {
    onSelectHandler(categoryName, selectedItemIds)
  }, [categoryName, selectedItemIds]);

  return (
    <ul className="card__inner">
      {props.items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <CheckboxItem
            isChecked={selectedItemIds.includes(item.id)}
            id={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            price={item.price}
            category={item.category}
            key={item.id}
            onClick={clickHandler}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Here's the function in **App.js** which receives the data and then updates the `selections` state.

```
  const [selections, setSelections] = useState({
    chairs: 2,
    tables: 8,
    "large tables": [10, 12]
  });

  const selectionHandler = (selectedCategoryName, selectedItemIds) => {
    setSelections((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [selectedCategoryName]: selectedItemIds,
    }));
  };
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way I can either include the dependency in `useEffect` without it triggering an infinite loop or there's an alternative way of lifting the state, perhaps without `useEffect`?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) from React to memoize `selectionHandler`. This way you can safely add it in the dependency array:

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
```

```js
const selectionHandler = useCallback((selectedCategoryName, selectedItemIds) => {
  setSelections((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [selectedCategoryName]: selectedItemIds,
  }));
}, []);
```